# Is it possible for an external gradle annotationProcessor to imply its dependencies?

Tags: gradle, groovy

As far as I can tell, you need to manually specify what's going to be in the classpath when using Gradle's annotationProcessor dependency handler. I'm looking for a way to possibly automate that.

It feels like I'm missing something. Let's say I have an annotation processor called `my.processor`, with [javapoet](https://github.com/square/javapoet) as a dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.squareup:javapoet:1.13.0'
}
```

However, when it's time to apply my processor to a given class, I need to manually specify that JavaPoet has to be present in the classpath:

```
dependencies {
    // (other dependencies)
    annotationProcessor 'my:processor:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.squareup:javapoet:1.13.0'
}
```

If I don't, it's going to throw an exception (`TypeDefNotFoundException` if I recall correctly) lamenting that  it can't find one of the javapoet classes - obviously, since it's not in the classpath.

Is it possible to just write:

```
dependencies {
    // (other dependencies)
    annotationProcessor 'my:processor:1.0.0'
}
```

and have the presence of javapoet (or any other dependency of `my.processor`) be implied?

Comment: "Is it possible to just write [...] and have the presence of javapoet (or any other dependency of my.processor) be implied?" - The question reads like you tried that and it didn't work.  Is that the case?

Comment: Sort of? I didn't try anything specific, just checked if it did that out of the box. It didn't, I'm asking if there's some other less obvious way I don't know about.

Comment: you can define a list of your dependencies as a constant `def MY_PROC = [ 'my:processor:1.0.0', 'com.squareup:javapoet:1.13.0', ]` and use it in `dependencies` like so `annotationProcessor MY_PROC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky.  The short answer is NO, but here is my logic.

Marking your `my-processor` library as an `annotationProcessor` should pull over your transient dependencies which means `javapoet` will be on the classpath through the `implementation` dependency, but it would not be marked as an `annotationProcessor` in your project. Just because `javapoet` COULD be used an an `annotationProcessor` doesn't mean it SHOULD be.  Hence you must specify both annotation processors because your 3rd party project uses both.  Gradle can't read your mind.

The only way I'd know if it would have any chance of working is if you specified `javapoet` as an `annotationProcessor` in your `my-processor` project and by specifying `my-processor` as an annotationProcess that had some transient dependency relationship and gradle would 'know' to pull over `javapoet` too as an `annotationProcessor`.  But I don't know if that exists or not, and as I describe it; it sounds like a big reach.  Here's why:

Consider this alternative that `my-processor` had some annotations in its code base from `javapoet` that it used to function internally.  But it used `javapoet` as an `annotationProcessor` to create some code for its library to work, but wasn't piggy backing off a 3rd party project also using `javapoet`.  In that case the fact that `javapoet` was marked as an `annotationProcessor` wouldn't also be applied to other projects that were dependent on `my-processor`.  In which case you'd only register `my-processor` and not `javapoet` and that would be the expected case because the 3rd party project only used `my-processor` and NOT `javapoet`.  That case would look exactly like what I described above with `my-project` declaring `annotationProcessor` for `javapoet`.  In one case you want isolation from dependencies' usage of annotationProcessor.  And in the desired case you want it to transiently be applied to 3rd party cases.  But the configuration of both of those situations is exactly the same so you couldn't differentiate what the developer wanted to happen.  So my guess is NO you have to specify both annotation processors in your projects that directly use those libraries.

Comment: You're right. Come think of it, this was a pretty stupid question. How could Gradle know about the `implementation` of the processor?
A solution I came up with is to set it up as a Maven repository, and specify the needed libraries in the POM file.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a stupid question at all.  It's tricky because of the annotationProcessor delineation :-)